# hide only active element - not all

Tags: javascript, jquery

Now script hide all elements ".buttonshow". 
I'd like **hide only clicked (active) element ".buttonshow".**

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qya3xp76/12/)

line 5 is key i think

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hideDiv").hide();
    $('.buttonshow').click(function () {
        $(this).next(".hideDiv").slideToggle();
        $(".buttonshow").hide();
    });
    $('.buttonhide').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().slideToggle();
        $(".buttonshow").show();
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(this).hide()` instead of `$('.buttonshow').hide()`?

Answer (score 1):

Then use `$(this)`:

```
 $('.buttonshow').click(function () {
     $(this).hide().next(".hideDiv").slideToggle(); //<-- hide self
 });
 $('.buttonhide').click(function () {
     $(this).show().parent().slideToggle(); //<-- show self
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".hideDiv").hide();
      $('.buttonshow').click(function () {
         $(this).next(".hideDiv").slideToggle();
         $(this).hide();
      });

 $('.buttonhide').click(function () {
     $(this).parent().slideToggle();
     $(this).show();
 });
```